# Interface as functions in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an android library that contains some views. Naturally these views can emit events.

I have an interface called (just for the purpose of this question) `Listener`. If I wrote the library in Java things would look like this:

```java
public interface Listener {
    void onEvent();
}
```

```java
public class SomeView extends FrameLayout {
    // Some more functions and implementation details

    public void setListener(Listener l) { ... }
}
```

When using this view in a Kotlin activity I can use the `setListener` like this:

```
someViewInstance.setListener {
    // implementation
}
```

I want to write my library in Kotlin, but it might be used in Java code as well, so I want to provide and interface for the listener just like a regular view (like above) but have the option for Kotlin code to use the function implementation:

```
interface Listener {
    fun onEvent()
}
```

when I try to use `setListener` like above in my Kotlin test activity I get a compilation error saying that the function expects type `Listener` but got `() -> Unit`.

Is there a way to enable this kind of implementation in Kotlin without having to create a new function for this?

I thought about having just one function that receives `() -> Unit` but then it look weird in the Java code (`Function1` etc.).

Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna check this link : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [SAM-conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions),

> Just like Java 8, Kotlin supports SAM conversions. This means that Kotlin function literals can be automatically converted into implementations of Java interfaces with a single non-default method, as long as the parameter types of the interface method match the parameter types of the Kotlin function.

But

> Note that SAM conversions only work for interfaces, not for abstract classes, even if those also have just a single abstract method.
>   Also note that this feature **works only for Java interop**; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

So, you can't write a simple Kotlin code to simulate this call.

---

In **Java**, if you write a

```
public interface Listener {
    void onEvent(); // SAM: Single Abstract Method. Only 1 is allowed
}
```

And you have a

```
public class SomeView extends FrameLayout {
    // skip the constructors

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then you can do such a fancy call in Kotlin, thanks to SAM-conversion:

```
SomeView(this).setListener {} // asking a parameter with type () -> Unit for setListener
                              // Then parenthesis of function call can be omitted
// setListener function can also accept a parameter with type Listener
// by object : Listener {}
```

But if you convert that Java file into Kotlin, the code will report an error, due to the reason mentioned above. You have to implement a `SomeView.setListener(() -> Unit)` function by yourself, for example

```
fun SomeView.setListener(l: () -> Unit) {
    listener = object : Listener{
        override fun onEvent() {
            l()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can define your interface as suggested and also add an extension that allows the usage of a lambda which is more idimatic for Kotlin code.

```
class SomeView {
    fun setListener(l: Listener) {}
}

fun SomeView.setListener(l: () -> Unit) = setListener(object : Listener {
    override fun onEvent() = l()
})
```

In Java, you would still be able to pass the `Listener` implementation.

Comment: I tried to define the extension function in the same file as the class itself and then use it in the activity, but it didn't work. Only when I defined the extension in the activity did it work. I am working on a library so it is not an option to define the extension with the activity. Have I missed something?

Comment: it's important that you don't define the extension inside a class body but on top-level

Comment: It's not in the type body. I defined it right after the class definition. After the last `}` of the class

Comment: what happens if you import it in your activity? try `import packagename.extensionName` with your extension named `extensionName` and defined in package `packagename`

Answer (score 3):

for Kotlin 1.4+. It can use SAM-conversion for Kotlin functions if you mark an interface as a "functional" interface:

```
fun interface Listener {
    fun onEvent()
}
```